# How to display user entered information using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, document.write

I have a form code tat will allow the user to enter information. I'm trying to display certain parts of that information onto a new page using javascript. Basically, the page is meant to have the user enter information and have the name, date, time, and email display in a new tab or page. But I can't seem to have it displayed. Can anyone help me?

```
<html lang="en" >
    <head>
    <title>Shy Music Booking Confirmation</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="music.css" type="text/css" />

<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="form">
    <header><h1>Shy Music Private Lessons</h1></header>

<script type="text/javascript">

      function addtext()
      {
         var userName = document.booking.userName.value;
         var userDate = document.booking.userDate.value;
         var userTime = document.booking.userTime.value;
         var userEmail = document.booking.userEmail.value;

         document.writeln("Thank you! You have just entered the following:");
         document.writeln("<pre>");
         document.writeln("Name: " + userName);
         document.writeln("Date: " + userDate);
         document.writeln("Time: " + userTime);
      }
    </script>
</head>
<hr>
<form name="booking">
<h1>Book a Slot Here!</h1>
    <label for="userName">Name: <br><input type = "text" name = "userName"></label>      <br><br>
    <label for="userEmail">E-mail Address: <br><input type = "email" name = "userEmail"></label><br><br>
<label for="userPhone">Phone Number: <br><input type = "tel" name = "userPhone">    </label><br><br>
<label for="userInstrument">Instrument: 
<select>
<option>Guitar</option>
<option>Drums</option>
<option>Piano</option>
</select>
</label>
<br><br>
<label for="userTime">
Preffered Time: 
<select>
<option>9:00</option>
<option>9:30</option>
<option>10:00</option>
<option>10:30</option>
<option>11:00</option>
<option>11:30</option>
<option>12:00</option>
<option>12:30</option>
<option>1:00</option>
<option>1:30</option>
<option>2:00</option>
<option>2:30</option>
<option>3:00</option>
<option>3:30</option>
<option>4:00</option>
<option>4:30</option>
</select>
</label>
<select>
<option>AM</option>
<option>PM</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
    <label for="userDate">Date: <br><input type = "date" name = "userDate"></label><br><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit" >
<form action="#">
<input type="button" value = "Back" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1)" />
</form>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try using something other than `document.write` to display your information.

Comment: What else should I use?

Comment: Create an HTML element for output and give it an id. Then do `document.getElementById(element_id).innerHTML = [text]` inside your function.

Comment: Yes, I was able to get it to work. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Great! I'll make an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was working on this for a lot of time, but it wasn't working. But, I tried it recently and it worked! I hope this was helpful.

```
<html>
<head>
<h1> Welcome</h1>
</head>
<body>
<p> Enter name: </p>
<input id="name" name="name"class="Name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Full name" required>`
<input type="Submit" onclick="submitted()"> <br> <br>
<a id="new" href="www.google.com"> </a>
<script>

      function submitted()
      {
        var a = document.getElementById("name").value;

        if (a=="")
        {
      document.getElementById("new").innerHTML="";
      alert("Please Enter a valid name!");
        }
        else if (a==" ") {
        document.getElementById("new").innerHTML=""
      alert("Please Enter a valid name!");
        }
        else
        {
          document.getElementById("new").innerHTML="Thank you, " + a + ". " + "Click here to continue.";
        }
      }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Or, slightly tightened, as a working snippet:

```js
function submitted()
{
   var a = document.getElementById("name").value.trim();
   document.getElementById("new").innerHTML=
     a===""?"":"Thank you, " + a + ". " + "Click here to continue.";
}
```

```html
<p> Enter name: </p>
    <input id="name" name="name"class="Name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Full name" required>
    <input type="Submit" onclick="submitted()"> <br> <br>
    <a id="new" href="www.google.com"> </a>
```

Comment: Hi @soham, welcome to Stackoverflow! I hope you don't mind me editing your answer. But it is always a good idea to include a woking [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) to demonstrate your code (which I also tightened a little bit).

Comment: @cars10m Thank you for editing my answer. I am new to stack overflow. I used to ask questions, but I answered for the first time, so I don't have much experience. Thank you again!

Comment: Good to hear that I did not offend you. Keep trying out that snippet feature!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code was that you were using `document.write` in a dynamic setting. When using it in this context, `document.write` will erase the content of the current document and replace it with the text specified by its parameters. For this reason, `document.write` is commonly regarded as poor way to represent and insert text/data. And it typically affects the plethora of beginners learning JavaScript. Here are some alternatives you should keep in mind:

- `element.innerHTML`: Like I said in the comments. Use `.innerHTML` to insert the formatted HTML into document through an element on the page. It doesn't necessarily have to be specified by an `id` attribute. It can very well be given by any other form of element obtainment.
- `node.appendChild`: This method is more DOM-friendly than the first. It allows you to insert a node at the end of the body of the element specified by `node`. For example:

  ```
  var form = document.myForm,
      new_element = document.createElement('input');

  new_element.type = "button";
  new_element.value = "Submit";

  form.appendChild( new_element );
  ```

I hope this helped.